# Redirect due to "malicious or dangerous" code

Tags: templates

All my efforts at "view rendered" are met with 
"Error: The link you are being redirected to contained some potentially malicious or dangerous code. We recommend you hit the back button and email [my email] to report the link that generated this message.

This is my exploratory effort upon installation.

Comment: What version of expressionengine, and do you have any 3rd party add-ons installed?

Comment: What is throwing the error? Virus scanner? Browser?  something else? ExpressionEngine?

Comment: Actually, that is in the core_lang.php file, so it must be EE.  It is for "redirect_xss_fail".

Comment: What does the url you are trying to open look like?

Comment: It's the most recent version of EE 3.5.6, and I have no idea what's throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen a few weeks ago. I don't remember all the details (of course), but it was an Apache ModSecurity rule being triggered by navigating to the admin. Some of the url words flagged a security keyword.

Getting around this involved finding the rule being triggered and removing it.

Look at ModSecurity Tools in WHM:

1. Find the rule id being triggered for the url you were trying to access.
2. Override the rule:
   On Rules List > Edit Rules add in a directive to override the rule when matched, like (with the correct id instead of 123456).

:

```
<locationmatch "^/my-custom-ee-admin-name/index.php.*">
  SecRuleRemoveById 123456
</locationmatch>
```

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/ModSecurity+Tools

[examples of location matching for disabling modsec rules](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjJ1PzktYvUAhXLh1QKHUOSCjQQFggxMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresources.infosecinstitute.com%2Favoiding-mod-security-false-positives-white-listing%2F&usg=AFQjCNFaKXxHzBvErDhWHCVrXvMEqAh_rw&sig2=klqcR4a9CSwcGuy9KTCAyw)